# Android Webview: HTML Content is Overlapping

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

Html content is overlapping when large content is loading in the web view. Is there a solution
for this problem?

```
 reportView.setBackgroundColor(0);
 reportView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 reportView.setInitialScale(100);
 reportView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 reportView.clearView();
```

Comment: We need a bit more code (Layout and Java) to be able to help you :)

Comment: try to use  a neww css file as per your requirement

Comment: contact to your mobile site developer for making site  for moblie properly!!!!!!

Comment: it works  reportView.setBackgroundColor(0); removed ,so i want transport  web view.if not transparent it works

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);
```

in webview settings.
Fixed Html content is overlapping issue, when large content is loading in the web view.

Answer (score 1):

webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.TEXT_AUTOSIZING);

In addition  to the above line, trying to reset webview instances every time
.